# Python decorator optional argument

Tags: python, decorator

```
from functools import wraps
def logged(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print func.__name__ + " was called"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_logging

@logged
def f(x):
   """does some math"""
   return x + x * x

print f.__name__  # prints 'f'
print f.__doc__   # prints 'does some math'
```

Given this sample code, how would I be able to do `@logged(variable)`?

I tried this

```
from functools import wraps
def logged(func):
    def outer(var):
        @wraps(func)
        def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
            print func.__name__ + " was called"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return with_logging
    return outer
```

I was hoping to execute like this:  logged(func)(session_variable)

But doesn't work.
Any idea? I want to be able to do  @logged and @logged(var)  ( or even @logged(var1, var2))
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick here is, you have to introspect what you are given:

```
def logged(*setting_args, **setting_kwargs):
    no_args = False
    if len(setting_args) == 1 \
        and not setting_kwargs \
        and callable(setting_args[0]):
        # We were called without args
        func = setting_args[0]
        no_args = True

    def outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
            print "{} was called".format(func.__name__)
            print "Setting args are: {}".format(setting_args)
            print "Setting keyword args are: {}".format(setting_kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return with_logging

    if no_args:
        return outer(func)
    else:
        return outer
```

This will work with any of the following:

```
# No arguments
@logged
def some_function(x):
    pass

# One or more arguments
@logged(1, 2, 3)
def some_function(x):
    pass

# One or more keyword arguments
@logged(key=1, another_key=2)
def some_function(x):
    pass

# A mix of the two
@logged(1, 2, key=3)
def some_function(x):
    pass
```

It *will not* work if it is called with only one callable argument:

```
# This will break.
@logged(lambda: "Just for fun")
def some_function(x):
    pass
```

There is no way to tell the difference between a single callable setting and a no-arg invocation of the decorator.  However, you can pass a garbage keyword arg to get around even that if you need to:

```
# This gets around the above limitation
@logged(lambda: "Just for fun", ignored=True)
def some_function(x):
    pass
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This helped me implement a `required_params()` decorator.

Answer (score 6):

The question is more than 6 years old, and already has answers.
I bumped into same situation - had to update a decorator used at lot of places in the code, and wanted to add an optional argument.

I am able to get it done, using a different approach - from the book ***Python CookBook 3rd Edition***, ***Chapter 9 - 9.6. Defining a Decorator That Takes an Optional***
Argument. It takes the problem, presents the solution and end it with a discussion (just great).

---

**Solution**: for **Python 3.3+**

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def logged(func=None, *, var1=None, var2=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(logged, var1=var1, var2=var2)

    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print func.__name__ + " was called"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_logging
```

with above you can do either of the following:

```
@logged
def f(x):

@logger(var1)
def f(x):

@logger(var1, var2)
def f(x)
```

---

**Explanation** (best to look for it in the book)

> To understand how the code works, you need to have **a firm
>   understanding of how decorators get applied to functions** and their
>   calling conventions.

**1. Simple decorator such as this:**

```
# Example use
@logged
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The calling sequence is as follows:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add = logged(add)
```

> In this case, the function to be wrapped is simply passed to logged as
>   the first argument. Thus, in the solution, the first argument of
>   logged() is the function being wrapped. All of the other arguments
>   must have default values.

**2. Decorator taking arguments:**

```
@logged(level=logging.CRITICAL, name='example')
def spam():
    print('Spam!')
```

The calling sequence is as follows:

```
def spam():
    print('Spam!')

spam = logged(level=logging.CRITICAL, name='example')(spam)
```

The above last line, is how a decorator with arguments is called i.e. in the initial invocation of `logged()` the function to be decorated `spam()` is not passed, thus we set it optional in decorator i.e. `func=None` in `logged` definition. So, in the first call only the arguments are passed.

> This, in turn, forces the other arguments to be specified by keyword.
>   Furthermore, when arguments are passed, a decorator is supposed to
>   return a function that accepts the function and wraps it (see Recipe
>   9.5). To do this, the solution uses a clever trick involving **`functools.partial`**. **Specifically, it simply returns a partially applied
>   version of itself where all arguments are fixed except for the
>   function to be wrapped**.

Answer (score 0):

put the `def outer(var)` outward, that is

```
def outer(var):
    def logged(func):
        ...
```

, then use `@outer(somevar)` for your function, this would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is minor error in the code you tried. Instead of creating nested functions with arguments as `func` > `var` > `*args, **kwargs`, the order should be `var` > `func` > `*args, **kwargs`.

Below is the code snippet that would suffice your requirement.

```
from functools import wraps

def logged(var=None):
    def outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
            print func.__name__ + " was called"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return with_logging
    return outer
```

You may call this decorator as:

```
@logged
def func1():
    ...
```

OR,

```
@logged(xyz)
def func2():
    ...
```

To know more on how decorators work, refer article [Decorators with optional arguments](http://ydevel.tumblr.com/post/32728593201/decorators-with-optional-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative solution to Sean Vieira's could be:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect


def decorator_defaults(**defined_defaults):
    def decorator(f):
        args_names = inspect.getargspec(f)[0]

        def wrapper(*new_args, **new_kwargs):
            defaults = dict(defined_defaults, **new_kwargs)
            if len(new_args) == 0:
                return f(**defaults)
            elif len(new_args) == 1 and callable(new_args[0]):
                return f(**defaults)(new_args[0])
            else:
                too_many_args = False
                if len(new_args) > len(args_names):
                    too_many_args = True
                else:
                    for i in range(len(new_args)):
                        arg = new_args[i]
                        arg_name = args_names[i]
                        defaults[arg_name] = arg
                if len(defaults) > len(args_names):
                    too_many_args = True
                if not too_many_args:
                    final_defaults = []
                    for name in args_names:
                        final_defaults.append(defaults[name])
                    return f(*final_defaults)
                if too_many_args:
                    raise TypeError("{0}() takes {1} argument(s) "
                                    "but {2} were given".
                                    format(f.__name__,
                                           len(args_names),
                                           len(defaults)))
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@decorator_defaults(start_val="-=[", end_val="]=-")
def my_text_decorator(start_val, end_val):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                            f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@decorator_defaults(end_val="]=-")
def my_text_decorator2(start_val, end_val):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                            f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@my_text_decorator
def func1a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator()
def func2a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("-=[")
def func2b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator(end_val=" ...")
def func3a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("-=[", end_val=" ...")
def func3b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator("|> ", " <|")
def func4a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("|> ", " <|")
def func4b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator(end_val=" ...", start_val="|> ")
def func5a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("|> ", end_val=" ...")
def func5b(value):
    return value


print(func1a('My sample text'))  # func1a -=[My sample text]=-
print(func2a('My sample text'))  # func2a -=[My sample text]=-
print(func2b('My sample text'))  # func2b -=[My sample text]=-
print(func3a('My sample text'))  # func3a -=[My sample text ...
print(func3b('My sample text'))  # func3b -=[My sample text ...
print(func4a('My sample text'))  # func4a |> My sample text <|
print(func4b('My sample text'))  # func4b |> My sample text <|
print(func5a('My sample text'))  # func5a |> My sample text ...
print(func5b('My sample text'))  # func5b |> My sample text ...
```

Note: it has the same drawback where you can't pass 1 argument as function to decorator, but if you want this functionality on multiple decorators you can evade the code boilerplate.